# How to show that if $V \in C^{m \times m}$ unitary and $A \in C^{m \times m}$ then $||AV||_2=||A||_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How to show that if $V \in C^{m \times m}$ is unitary and $A \in C^{m \times m}$ then $$||AV||_2=||A||_2$$

Where $$||A||_2 = \sup_{ ||x||_2=1 } ||Ax||_2$$ and 
$$||AV||_2 = \sup_{ ||x||_2=1 } ||AVx||_2$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\|AV\|_2$ and $\|A\|_2$?  Are those the same as $\|AV\|$ and $\|A\|$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I made the correction in the question, defining each of the norms.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes those are the same. Thanks for noticing. I made the correction in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\Vert V x\Vert^2 = \langle V x,V x \rangle = \langle x , V^* V x \rangle = \langle x,x\rangle = \Vert x\Vert ^2 $$
for any $x$. So for any $x$ you have $\Vert Vx\Vert = \Vert x\Vert$.

Hence $V$ has norm $1$. $V^{-1}$ as well is unitary and so it has norm $1$.

Clearly $\Vert A V\Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert \Vert V\Vert = \Vert A\Vert$.

For the other inequality you have

$$\Vert A\Vert = \Vert AV V^{-1}\Vert \leq \Vert A V\Vert \Vert V^{-1}\Vert = \Vert AV\Vert\,.$$
Then $\Vert AV \Vert = \Vert A\Vert$.

Comment: I am agree with the first equality $||Vx||_2=||x||_2$. But I do not see how it follows inmediatly that $||AV||_2=||A||_2$

Comment: I've edited giving a more explicit version of the proof.

Comment: My original point was that since $V$ is an isometric isomorphism you can find a $x$ which attends the sup in the definition of $\Vert A\Vert$ and then cosider $y=V^{-1} x$, which will give you the sup in the other definition.